# Index or query tuning for complex predicates

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, optimization, index-tuning, cardinality-estimates

I'm struggling to identify effective indexes (or rewrite the query) to improve a query with the following confounding predicates:

- JOIN on a date from one table being in range - between two date fields on second table (one is nullable, one is not nullable in PK).
- The date used is actually the value in date field (nullable) +1.
- WHERE clauses includes OR logic on multiple flag fields.

The simplified version of the query is:

```
select
d.dim_date_id
,f.dim_provider_id
,f.dim_event_id
,d.date

from DWH.dbo.tbl_fact_outcome f
join   DWH.dbo.tbl_dim_date d on DATEADD(DAY,1,d.date) between f.known_from and f.known_to 

where
f.known_from > getdate()-12
and (d.flag_latest_day = 'Y' or  d.flag_end_of_month = 'Y'  or (d.flag_end_of_week = 'Y' AND d.flag_latest_week = 'Y'))
and d.flag_future_day = 'N'
and f.deleted = 0
```

tbl_fact_outcome has these indexes:

- PK clustered index on input_form_id, known_from
- Non-unique Nonclustered index on deleted, known_from, known_to (INCLUDES the required _dim_id fields)

tbl_dim_date has these indexes:

- PK clustered index on dim_date_id
- Non-unique nonclustered index on flag_future_day, date (INCLUDES relevant flag fields)

At present, it estimates 853 rows but returns 16,784.

Here is the query plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rydKb_3AI

Statistics are up to date.
I have tried re-ordering the covering indexes but no improvement.

I'm totally stumped as to what else to try with indexes or the code itself to improve performance, so any pointers appreciated.

---

**EDIT 05/07/2020**

Ruled out the following suggestions from StackOverflow:

- Filtered index (on deleted) on tbl_fact_outcome - less than 1% of records would be filtered out, so not worthwhile
- Filtered index (using entire WHERE clause from query) on tbl_dim_date - not possible to use OR in index
- Index on tbl_dim_date with INCLUDEd fields as key fields - tried this, made no difference, not used by optimizer.

---

**EDIT 06/07/2020 - table DDLs**

**tbl_dim_date**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_dim_date](
   [dim_date_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [date] [date] NULL,
   [day] [varchar](9) NULL,
   [month] [varchar](9) NULL,
   [month_of_calendar_year] [int] NULL,
   [day_of_calendar_year] [int] NULL,
   [year] [int] NULL,
   [flag_end_of_month] [char](1) NULL,
   [academic_year] [varchar](25) NULL,
   [flag_latest_month_snapshot] [char](1) NULL,
   [flag_latest_day] [char](1) NULL,
   [flag_future_day] [char](1) NULL,
   [InsertAuditKey] [int] NULL,
   [UpdateAuditKey] [int] NULL,
   [flag_end_of_week] [char](1) NULL,
   [flag_latest_week] [char](1) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [dim_date_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],


CONSTRAINT [dbotbl_dim_date_UC] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
   [date] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [JM_TEST_03072020] ON [dbo].[tbl_dim_date]
(
   [flag_future_day] ASC,
   [date] DESC
)
INCLUDE([dim_date_id],[flag_end_of_month],[flag_latest_day],[flag_end_of_week],[flag_latest_week])
```

**tbl_fact_outcome**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_fact_outcome](
    [known_from] [date] NOT NULL,
    [known_to] [date] NULL,
    [source_id] [int] NULL,
    [input_form_id] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [dim_provider_id] [int] NULL,
    [dim_event_id] [int] NULL,
    [dim_question_id] [int] NULL,
    [dim_answer_id] [int] NULL,
    [dim_form_id] [int] NULL,
    [count_of_outcomes] [int] NULL,
    [InsertAuditKey] [int] NULL,
    [UpdateAuditKey] [int] NULL,
    [LNK_FORM_OUTCOME_ID] [int] NULL,
    [answer] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [deleted] [bit] NULL,
    [dim_latest_provider_id] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbotbl_Fact_Outcome] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [input_form_id] ASC,
    [known_from] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_tbl_fact_outcome_deleted_known_from_known_to_includes] ON [dbo].[tbl_fact_outcome]
(
    [deleted] ASC,
    [known_from] ASC,
    [known_to] ASC
)
INCLUDE([dim_provider_id],[dim_event_id],[dim_question_id],[dim_answer_id],[dim_form_id])
```

**Query plans after following GMass DBA's suggestions**
NB data is different since initial run but issue not affected

- Date join made SARGable by using > and < rather than between, and changing +1 to date from tbl_dim_date, to -1 on known_from on tbl_fact_outcome
- New index on tbl_dim_date (date, flag_future_day INCLUDE other columns)
- New index in tbl_fact_outcome (known_from, deleted, known_to INCLUDE other columns)

Re-run of initial query prior to changes (apart from getdate()-5 instead of getdate()-12 last week) - plan essentially the same:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJKN3og1w

Query with amended date logic plus new indexes on each table (only one used).
Improved, but estimates still way off:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy_gsoxkw

Query plan after amending date j

Comment: First issue I see here is joining condition column DATEADD(DAY,1,d.date). This makes your search predicate non-SARGable. Make it SARGable and I think your issue should be solved. Link --> https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/12/the-two-ways-to-fix-non-sargable-queries/

Comment: @Nikita - Done - at least for the indexes being used. I have been adding removing various indexes and combinations over the past week, but these are the ones actually used currently.

Comment: @Learning_DBAdmin - thanks. I was hoping to avoid adding any new columns (ie computed date +1)  but pretty sure there's not another way to make that SARGable?

Comment: Between should be inclusive - since you're handling dates you could say that `d.date > f.known_from AND d.date < f.known_to`. I also personally don't really like OR conditions, especially when nested - I'd probably try having a computed column as a bit and query for 1's (but I'm not really that sure about this last one).

Comment: Yes, Instead of adding +1 - You may use > and <. This works in almost all scenario and is also sargable. You might check --> https://bertwagner.com/2017/08/22/how-to-search-and-destroy-non-sargable-queries-on-your-server/                                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853774/is-this-date-comparison-condition-sarg-able-in-sql

Comment: @GMassDBA - this example returns different results... in my query the date (as it is in the table) can be the day before known_from (because date + 1 is BETWEEN, so is includes), but in your example it must be at least the day after known_from - so two days are missing.

Comment: @Learning_DBAAdmin - sorry if I'm being slow but I can't work out logic that will give the same results using > and <. Eg see comment above. As per that article, potentially converting data type might help somehow but I'm not sure exactly what I should change in my example?

Comment: what is the goal of this tuning? how fast this query should work?

Comment: @JShark - you're absolutely right. I missed that, sorry. From the plan, I'm seeing that the "seek" on tbl_dim_date is reading 26K rows and change, but only returning ~850. Since you already have a filter  predicate for `f.known_from`, I'd say to shift the date math in there to the f table, like `d.date >= DATEADD(DAY,-1,f.known_from) and d.date < f.known_to`. Also, I'd stick with an index on `d.date, flag_future_date`, and include all the columns joined with the OR conditions. On tbl_fact_outcome maybe have an index on `known_from, deleted, known_to` ?

Comment: Well, if you are unable to change your query and new query is giving different set of result then, safest method is to add this as a new computed column and add an NC index over it. Almost all other methods include code change.

Comment: GMassDBA - using -1 on known_from (instead of +1 on date), and adding those indexes changed the shape of the query (no eager spool) , and appears to have reduced cost but estimates are still way off.
Optimizer chose to use existing index on tbl_dim_date.
I've updated initial post with latest query plans.

Comment: @JShark, your join predicate can be changed to: `on d.date > f.known_from and d.date <= DATEADD(DAY,-1 f.known_to)` Not sure if -1 is accepted, but you can use DATESUB instead. The logic strikes me as a bit odd, but that is perhaps the way it should be?

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you try indexed view?

```
CREATE VIEW vw WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
SELECT d.dim_date_id
    ,f.dim_provider_id
    ,f.dim_event_id
    ,d.date
    ,f.input_form_id
    ,f.known_from
from dbo.tbl_fact_outcome f
join  dbo.tbl_dim_date d on DATEADD(DAY,1,d.date) between f.known_from and f.known_to 

where
(d.flag_latest_day = 'Y' or  d.flag_end_of_month = 'Y'  or (d.flag_end_of_week = 'Y' AND d.flag_latest_week = 'Y'))
and d.flag_future_day = 'N'
and f.deleted = 0


CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_vw ON vw (known_from, date, input_form_id);

SELECT dim_date_id
    ,dim_provider_id
    ,dim_event_id
    ,date
FROM vw 
WHERE known_from > getdate()-12
```

2. solution with indexed computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_dim_date ADD date1 AS 
CASE WHEN (flag_latest_day = 'Y' or  flag_end_of_month = 'Y'  or (flag_end_of_week = 'Y' AND flag_latest_week = 'Y'))
and flag_future_day = 'N' THEN  DATEADD(DAY,1,date) ELSE NULL END

CREATE INDEX ix1 ON tbl_dim_date(date1);

select
d.dim_date_id
,f.dim_provider_id
,f.dim_event_id
,DATEADD(DAY,-1,d.date1) AS date
from DWH.dbo.tbl_fact_outcome f
join   DWH.dbo.tbl_dim_date d on date1 between f.known_from and f.known_to 

where
f.known_from > getdate()-12
and f.deleted = 0
```

Comment: Would prefer to avoid a whole new object - and in this case I don't think an indexed view would work because it would need to sit in a separate database.
First choice would be to add indexes or amend query, second choice is to create additional fields in existing objects (ie potentially 2 computed columns in tbl_dim_date).

Comment: @JShark, I added solution with computed column but I'm not sure it works much faster than your original query